# How to say it in slang french ?

Tags: québec

How to say "you're so amazing and I'm your biggest fan in the world! I'll support you forever, I love you" in french? Slang french!

Comment: This is actually no slang English... Strange to translate it in slang French if you ask me. There are also different levels of slang from where I see it, Who do you want to talk to, how old is he/she ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Tu est vraiment incroyable. J'suis ton plus grand fan dans le monde. Je te supporterai a jamais. Je t'aime a la folie.

Comment: Je dirais plutôt "je te soutiendrai à jamais"

Comment: "Tu est" --> Tu es (or T'es)
"a jamais" --> à jamais
"a la folie" --> à la folie

Comment: @cl-r Le tag Québec rend très clair que "J'te kif à mort" n'est pas acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a young man from Paris and this is how i'd say this:
T'es trop dar, j'suis ton plus grand fan. J'te soutiendrai toujours, tu déchires.

Comment: L'argot dépend en grande partie de la région où se trouve l'interlocuteur. Je ne fais que donner une version que vous pourriez trouver en Ile de France. Une personne du Sud emploierait surement d'autres termes. Sinon restez sur des traductions telles que "j'te kiff à donf" qui ne se disent plus depuis une dizaine d'année.